# How to only allow non-decimal positive integer number in input number field with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Meaning: 0, 01, 0.01,a, - not allow

I try using this jquery but it still allow me to input 0, 02, 1.2, etc

```
$(document).on('keyup keypress', '.numeric-only', function() {
    var aValue = $(this).val();
    if ($.isNumeric(aValue) === false) {
        $(this).val(aValue.slice(1, -1));
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="">
    <input type="number" class="form-control quan numeric-only" min="1" step="1" minlength="1" value="'.$qty.'"/>
</div>
```

I already manage to validate the input with php but I also want to validate it with jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex replacing chars that is not numbers:

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    var onlyNumbers = $th.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, function(str) { return ''; } );
    var intValue = parseInt(onlyNumbers);
    if(intValue) {
        $th.val(intValue);
    } else {
        $th.val(0);
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f68yxfho/1/

**Update:** Parsing to int to prevent left zeros, as commented by @casraf

Comment: still allow me to input 000, 082, so how can I make that the fist number not start with a 0

Comment: you can also `parseInt` after the replacement

Comment: You should only call `val()` if the value has changed.

Comment: @oriadam I used val() to set just once. The other I used to get the value. http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: could you also tell me how you could limit the maximum value to be 99 or maxlength equivalent for input number